# Are rodent repellent devices safe for snakes?

Tags: safety, multi-pet-families, snakes, exotic-pets, rodents

We have young curious large breed dogs who make using mouse traps and poison difficult and/or dangerous.  We also have a ball python who lives in his terrarium, not free roaming.

All information I have found about electronic repellent devices say they are OK for dogs but to keep hamsters and other rodents away.  I can't find anything about the affect on snakes. Google just gives me a long list about using/preventing/pros/cons of snakes eating mice and rats.  Is this a viable option for iur home?

Comment: the frequency of electronic rodent repellers is probably too high for snakes to hear https://www.thesprucepets.com/are-snakes-bothered-by-loud-noises-1239469  as a side note some of the low cost rodent repellers are even safe for rodents some of them do not work at all.wellcome to pets.

Comment: I'd suggest using a dog-safe means to poison them. Professional exterminators put poisonous baits into a tube so it's unaccessable by cats and dogs. The tubes actually increase the chance of rodents eating it. They [look like this](https://goo.gl/images/QsTo5p)

Answer (score 2):

The elecronic repellers appear to work by making a high-pitched sound. Snakes don't hear all too well. I haven't seen mine react to any loud noises, like music or fireworks. If there's anything they're going to hear, it'll be the lower vibrations through the ground. I wouldn't worry in this case.

As for the dog-safe poison Elmy suggested, be advised that snakes would most likely be able to enter them if a rat or mouse can. Or at very least too close for comfort. So be advised if you let them free-roam for their exercise.